# Differentiate touch events from mouse events in Firefox in fixed DIV

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, dom-events, touch-event

I got this custom scrollbar that works fine everywhere, except in that fixed DIV. I'm testing with an Asus laptop with a touch screen (dunno if it matters).

So, on "regular" DIV, when I try to scroll by touching the screen, it triggers a `wheel` event and it works wonderful. On the fixed DIV, it triggers a `mousemove` event and I have no idea how to handle it.

I'm guessing that if I can detect if the event is trigger by touch or the mouse, I would be able to do some specific behavior, but the events look exactly the same. I obviously can't do custom behavior for all `mousemove` events because the user needs to be able to move his mouse without scrolling stuff.

NB: I think the issue came from the fact that the DIV I want to scroll is fixed, but I am not 100% sure (still pretty confident though).

Comment: Information is not enough to tell you anything. What "custom scrollbar" are you using? Did you try to scroll fixed DIV content without custom scrollbar?

Comment: I use [link](https://github.com/mattbalmer/mb-scrollbar), I added some functionalities to match my needs. The scrollbar is actually working fine, and it works on the fixed DIV in Chrome and IE, it is just with Firefox where I have the issue.
(I'm talking about the latest version of Chrome, IE and Firefox).

Comment: did you see the problem in Firefox with fixed div scrolling if you do not use custom scrollbar?

Comment: look at [this link](https://github.com/mattbalmer/mb-scrollbar/issues/5) - "Get it working on touch devices". Author wrote that experimental branch is "feature/touch"